# Please explain type assertion

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
// Type Assertion
let value: any = "Asim Hussain";
let len: number = (<string>value).length;
```

I don't really understand this. Please explain!

Comment: I don't understand it either. If `value` is going to be used as a string, why not just declare `let value: string = "...";` in the first place?

Comment: And since the value is already assigned to string, `: string` shouldn't be necessary either right? It should be the same with `let value = "..."`

Answer (score 1):

`let value: any = "Asim Hussain";`

This lets the variable `value` to be in any kind of type. It can be an integer, string, array, object.. Well, **any**thing!

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain"; // OK

value = 0; // OK
value = []; // OK
```

---

`let len: number = (<string>value).length;`

This forces the variable `len` to be in the number type, which **only** allows **number**s such as 0, 0.233, etc.

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain;" 
let len: number = (<string>value).length;

len = "213"; // Error
len = 213; // OK
len = value; // Error
len = value.length; // OK
```

The `.length` function returns a number, which is what the varable desires.

Answer (score 1):

`let value: any = "Asim Hussain";`
The variable `value` can contain anything (type `any`)

`let len: number = (<string>value).length;`
The variable `len` can only contain number (type `number`)
The `value` (type `any`) is cast into a type `string`.
`(<string>value)` == `value.toString()`
Tha variable `len` is set to the `length` of this `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling typescript that you know more than typescript.

**Example 1:**

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain"
const t = value.map(s => s)
```

Result: Typescript won't give me any errors.

**Example 2**

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain"
const t = (<string>value).map(s => s)
```

Result: Typescript lets me know *'Property map does not exist on string'*

**Example 3**

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain"
const len = value.length
```

Result: The type of len would be `any` aswell.

**Example 3**
I tell Typescript that I'm using length of a string

```
let value: any = "Asim Hussain"
const len = (<string>value).length
```

Results: Typescript knows that len is a number since String.prototype.length returns a number.